# Difference between a Spring datasource and a Tomcat datasource?

Tags: spring, tomcat, datasource

What is the difference between a Spring datasource and Tomcat datasource? Any pro's / con's? Is there a favored choice?

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941523/if-i-create-a-spring-datasource-do-i-still-need-to-define-the-datasource-inside ?

Comment: I agree that the questions are somewhat related, the previous question is all about the implementation. This one however, is more about if there a differences between the two and why we should or should not make a choice for a specific implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a Tomcat datasource you have to drop the JDBC driver JAR file(s) in Tomcat's classpath (the `Tomcat/lib`). This is sometimes not affordable/possible, for example when it concerns 3rd party hosting with zero server admin rights. When using a Spring managed datasource, it's sufficient to just drop the JDBC driver JAR file(s) in webapp's classpath (the `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`). Plus, I'd imagine that you've in Spring the additional benefit that you don't need to grab the `DataSource` manually. Also, you have the freedom of choosing a specific connection pool. Also, Tomcat ships with DBCP builtin as default connection pool which is not the [best choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) per se. With Spring, you could for example choose [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) above DBCP without the need to fiddle with Tomcat default configuration/classpath.

Comment: it is better to use tomcat data-source with hibernate? or should use C3P0 or BoneCP with hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datasource in the Spring config, you associate it with a  Tomcat datasource when you are in a web application. You can associate it with something else, for example Spring DriverManagerDataSource when you run unit tests.